# How can I use the chart.addButton() method?

Tags: highcharts

A Highcharts chart object has an addButton() method that seems to be undocumented in the Highcharts API. I assumed it would support the usual button options from navigation.buttonOptions so I experimented with this:

```
    chart.addButton({
            customButton: {
                text: 'Test',
                onclick: function () {
                    alert('clicked');
                },
                symbol: 'circle'
            }
        });
```

It creates a new (invisible!) button to the left of the Export contextButton but seems to have ignored all my options. Although the button is rendered invisible, it is highlighted on mouseover. But when I click on it, Highcharts generates the error "TypeError: d is undefined".

If someone has got this working, I'd appreciate some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: For me it works, make sure you have loaded exporting.js file, see: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/262/

Comment: @PawełFus: Thanks! My error was the use of {customButton: {}} wrapping the options.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons created in that way are accessible only via `chart.exportSVGElements`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/288/

To update title or fill color use `attr(options)`.

```
    var l = chart.exportSVGElements.length,
        button = chart.exportSVGElements[l - 2], //-2 because structure is: [button, symbol, button, symbol ...]
        symbol = chart.exportSVGElements[l - 1];

    button.attr({
        title: "New title!"
    });
    symbol.attr({
        fill: "green"
    });
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks. One difference. My button & symbol were in positions 0 & 1 of the array, presumably because I call addButton() in a callback from the Highcharts.Chart() constructor, rather than in a function assigned to the load event.

Do you know if it's possible to change the symbol? 
     symbol.attr({symbolName: "square"});
changes the attribute in the object but doesn't have any effect on the screen. Thanks again.

Comment: It's not possible. I think you should just remove that button and create new one..